my application isn't building it shows the error of the Cmake even though i have installed the cmake still i am not able to build the application
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking the license for package CMake 3.18.1 in C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package CMake 3.18.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install CMake 3.18.1 (revision: 3.18.1)".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':agora_rtc_engine'.


java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.sdk.InstallFailedException: Failed to install the following SDK components:
cmake;3.18.1 CMake 3.18.1
Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
i make changes in the signin report build gradle unintsall and install again same as thier files.there is problem with the package or what i am not able to understand but when i delete the agora_Rtc_engine the problem goes and my application build succesfully.Also i have downlaoded the cmake as it shows the error but not worked.
